# How to find cost of untagged resources in AWS using Cost explorer API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

We have 2 mandatory tags for every resource in AWS, we want to find the cost of the untagged resources, how is it possible to get the cost for the untagged resources ?

I checked through the Cost explorer API docs but didn't get much for untagged cost finding, any suggestions ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

As per Cost Explorer API documentation this specific filter that there should not be any other tag except the 2 mandatory tags is not possible. But we can do it other way round by applying filter on response from API.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Python, you can use this:

```
{
    "Tags": {
        "Key": "squad",
        "MatchOptions": ["ABSENT"]
    }
},
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).